# Dynamic Drop-down list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a dynamic drop-down list from column A in a table located in sheet("Historical Data").

This sheet is constantly being updated with new rows added and I would like to have my drop-down list updated automatically.

I have made a dynamic range `LastRow = Sheets("Historical Data").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row` and I am trying to put it in the formula.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
LastRow = Sheets("Historical Data").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
Worksheets("Chart").Activate
Range("C1").Select

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Historical Data!$A$3:A" & LastRow & ")"        
End With
```

I would like to do another drop-down from the header row. I have made another dynamic range; here is the code, but it does not work (I am pretty new to VBA) :

```
LastColumn = Sheets("Historical Data").Cells(2, Sheets("Historical Data").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range("G1").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="='Historical Data'!$T$2:" & LastColumn & "2"
```

An application-defined or object-defined error appears

Comment: Please note that using `Select` and `Activate` is bad practise and [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: The closing parenthesis you're adding lastly to the `Formula1` argument seems to serve no purpose

Comment: Where are you trying to remove the duplicates?

Comment: I did not posted the part that serves to remove duplicates since I could not update the drop-drown list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems

1. You have an extra bracket at the end as @TimStack mentioned
2. You have a space in the sheet name so you will have to pad it using the single quote.

Try this

```
Formula1:="='Historical Data'!$A$3:A" & LastRow
```

Note: Since you already have the code to remove duplicates, I will not address that query.